# MongoDB: $lookup with the same collection over subsequent documents

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I am relatively new with MongoDB and I have to switch the way I am dealing with specific data with a prior SQL structure. Therefore, the approach I am performing for sure is not wisest.

I have a list of work contracts with a bunch of information. At that level, they are not grouped by individuals. With the command `$lookup` I want to link each contract (document) with the following one, if is related to the same worker (individual).

There is a specific field, named 'ord_id', presented in the original .csv table, which ordered the documents. The example above is a simplified version of my collection. Those entries refer to the same individual `'worker_id': 158250`, but different others are present.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33a6bafdb40e7c44a4e663"),
    "worker_id" : "158250",
    "employer" : "139998",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2012-02-15T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2012-04-17T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "ord_id" : 484
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33a6bafdb40e7c44a4e665"),
    "worker_id" : "158250",
    "employer" : "5794265",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2012-10-17T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2012-11-15T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "ord_id" : 486
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33a6bafdb40e7c44a4e667"),
    "worker_id" : "158250",
    "employer" : "5794265",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2013-06-01T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2013-09-30T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "ord_id" : 488
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33a6bafdb40e7c44a4e666"),
    "worker_id" : "158250",
    "employer" : "5794265",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2013-02-01T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2013-05-31T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "ord_id" : 487
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33a6bafdb40e7c44a4e664"),
    "worker_id" : "158250",
    "employer" : "5794265",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2012-03-12T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2012-05-12T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "ord_id" : 485
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33a6bafdb40e7c44a4e668"),
    "worker_id" : "158250",
    "employer" : "5794265",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2015-06-01T02:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2015-11-30T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "ord_id" : 489
}
```

I wanted to add a new field named 'next' in each document which refers to the following contract, based on `ord_id`. In order to do so I performed the following command:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { ord_id: 1 } },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "mycollection",
           let: { id_lav: "$worker_id", curr_ord_id: "$ord_id" }, // 'curr_' is for current
           pipeline: [
               { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$worker_id", "$$id_lav" ] },
                         { $gt: [ "$ord_id", "$$curr_ord_id" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }, { $limit: 1 }
           ], 
           as: "next"
         }
    }, 
    { $unwind: { path: "$next", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true} }, 
    { $out: "mycollection" } ], 
    { allowDiskUse: true } );
```

However, there is for sure something I am missing. In fact, the 'next' field for some documents does not match the effective following one. For example, the document with 'ord_id' equal to 484 result to be linked to the one with 'ord_id' equal to 486 rather than 485. Others, instead, are linked properly. To solve the problem I have slightly modified the previous code in this way:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { ord_id: 1 } },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "mycollection",
           let: { id_lav: "$worker_id", curr_ord_id: "$ord_id" }, // 'curr_' is for current
           pipeline: [
               { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$worker_id", "$$id_lav" ] },
                         { $gt: [ "$ord_id", "$$curr_ord_id" ] },
                         { $eq: [ { $subtract: [ "$ord_id", "$$curr_ord_id" ] }, 1 ] },
                         { $or: [
                         { $eq: [ "$worker_id", "$$id_lav" ] },
                         { $gt: [ "$ord_id", "$$curr_ord_id" ] } 
                         ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }, { $limit: 1 }
           ], 
           as: "next"
         }
    }, 
    { $unwind: { path: "$next", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true} },
    { $out: "mycollection" } ], 
    { allowDiskUse: true } );
```

I do not understand completely why the first command does not give the desired output. Nonetheless, I am sure there are far better approaches to this issue. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your first query also [works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dwJ1Er01B0Z)

Comment: I do not think it does. In fact, the first document (with 'ord_id' equal to 484) results to have in the 'next' object the 'ord_id' 486 rather than 485.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're first pipeline was really close. the main issue is you have to `$sort` within the `$lookup`, the `$sort` you have right now is redundant (you could leave it so the new collection will be sorted after the `$out` so if you ever run in the same update in the future `$sort` will no longer be needed).

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "mycollection",
      let: {
        id_lav: "$worker_id",
        curr_ord_id: "$ord_id"
      },
      /** 'curr_' is for current*/
      pipeline: [
        {
          $sort: {
            ord_id: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$worker_id",
                    "$$id_lav"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$ord_id",
                    "$$curr_ord_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      as: "next"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$next",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$next", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true} },
  { $out: "mycollection" }
],
{
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m05LsdEbkdN)

Comment: Thank you! I see now it works with the MongoPlayground. Nonetheless, when I try it on a sample of my original collection (around 100,000 documents), it took quite a lot of time. Conversely, with the second version of the query, with the `$or` command, the new collection is generated quite fast.

Comment: Move the sort stage to be after the match phase in the jested pipeline